# Update contents of a table, using php rand()

Tags: php, html

I want to update a specific cell, using php rand() function. I don't understand how to exactly to do it.

Suppose`<td id="random1"></td>`
I want to update random1, using php.
Please help.

Sorry for not being able to show any work, because I'm not able to do any.

Comment: Do you have to use PHP or can you use JavaScript?  Changing values on a page like you are mentioned is very easily handled via JQuery or something like that as JavaScript is designed to make responsive pages.

Comment: Do you want a different number each time the page is loaded?

Comment: @apokryfos yes, that would be nice.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt No, only php. Skill test you see!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have PHP installed and just need help with the syntax.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

```
<td id="random<?php echo rand(); ?>"></td>
```

**EDIT**

> But, why the id's double quote doesn't end after random, but after the
>   php closing tag?

The entire output, including the tags `<?php ... ?>`, outputs a single number.

```
<td id="random<?php echo 'Text'; ?>"></td>
```

Comment: The code works perfectly fine. But, why the id's double quote doesn't end after random, but after the php closing tag?

Comment: Thanks again. Have a nice day.